# SQL Count(*) and then show column of those results

Tags: sql, oracle, count

This might be an easy question but im somewhat struggling with this.

```
SELECT
    DAY, PLACEMENT, SECLEVEL, COUNT(*)
FROM
    SECPEOPLE
GROUP BY
    DAY, PLACEMENT, SECLEVEL
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This returns duplicate people, who are at the same place, same day and same secLevel.

This is all fine and good, the **question is** how do i finish this query so that instead of this info, i get unique ID of duplicates?

Same table has column 'ID' which is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using analytic functions:

```
SELECT id, day, placement, seclevel
FROM (
    SELECT id, day, placement, seclevel, 
           count(*) over (partition by day, placement, seclevel) as cnt
    FROM secpeople
) t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way uses `exists`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM SECPEOPLE p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SECPEOPLE p2
              WHERE p2.day = p.day AND
                    p2.PLACEMENT = p.PLACEMENT AND
                    p2.SECLEVEL = p.SECLEVEL AND
                    p2.<id> <> p.<id>
              )
ORDER BY DAY, PLACEMENT, SECLEVEL
```

Answer (score 0):

use join with cte

```
with cte as
(
   SELECT
        DAY, PLACEMENT, SECLEVEL, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        SECPEOPLE
    GROUP BY
        DAY, PLACEMENT, SECLEVEL
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
    ) select a.id from cte join SECPEOPLE a on cte.DAY=a.DAY and cte.PLACEMENT=a.PLACEMENT and cte.SECLEVEL=a.SECLEVEL
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to use query you wrote

```
SELECT *
  FROM secpeople
 WHERE (day, placement, seclevel) IN 
   (-- this is your query
    SELECT DAY, PLACEMENT, SECLEVEL
    FROM SECPEOPLE
    GROUP BY DAY, PLACEMENT, SECLEVEL
    HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
   )
```